# Store the index values that add to a specific cumsum

Tags: python, pandas, list, cumsum

I have the following df

```
County      TotPerson  
Wayne       148        
Oakland     125        
Macomb      63         
Washtenaw   30          
Ingham      30          
Monroe      28          
Hillsdale   15          
Livingstone 15          
Jackson     14          
Lenawee     12
```

I'd like to store in different lists or a dictionary (it really doesn't matter) the counties that have a cumsum of no more than 190 from top to bottom.

The result should look something like this:

```
Group1
[Wayne]

Group2
[Oakland,Macomb]

Group3
[Washtenaw, Ingham, Monroe, Hillsdale, Livingstone, Jackson, Lenawee]
```

Comment: Can you explain your logic again for grouping? Why are Wayne and Oakland in their own groups?

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake, Oakland and Macomb should be on the same group.  Fixed it!

Comment: Wayne is on its own because of 148 + 125 = 273.  I need groups of no more than 190.  then Oakland and Macomb are on the same because 125 + 63 = 168, then I have the rest which is 144.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
groups = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    if len(df)>0:
        groups.append(df.loc[df.TotPerson.cumsum().lt(190)].County.tolist())
        df = df.loc[df.TotPerson.cumsum().ge(190)]

[['Wayne'],
 ['Oakland', 'Macomb'],
 ['Washtenaw',
  'Ingham',
  'Monroe',
  'Hillsdale',
  'Livingstone',
  'Jackson',
  'Lenawee']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Logic is kind of like reset when hit the limit 190

```
sumlm = np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: a+b if a+b < 190 else b,2,1)
id=sumlm.accumulate(df.TotPerson, dtype=np.object).eq(df.TotPerson).cumsum()

l=df.County.groupby(id).agg(list)
TotPerson
1                                              [Wayne]
2                                    [Oakland, Macomb]
3    [Washtenaw, Ingham, Monroe, Hillsdale, Livings...
Name: County, dtype: object
l.tolist()
```

Or try the for loop

```
l=[]
c=0
for i, y in enumerate(df.TotPerson):
     c += y
     if c >= 190:
        l.append(i)
        c = 0
df.County.groupby(df.index.isin(l).cumsum()).agg(list)
```

Comment: Very clever solution! It's good to learn something new (np.frompyfunc and accumulate). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can solve it using loop only but numpy.cumsum did not help me much on this problem. Hope it solves your problem.
    df=pd.read_clipboard()

```
cumsum=0
lst1=[]
lst2=[]
for j,i in zip(df.County,df.TotPerson):
    cumsum+=i
    if cumsum <=190:
        lst1.append(j)
    else:
        lst2.append(lst1)
        cumsum=i
        lst1=[j]
lst2.append(lst1)    
lst2 # This is the desired list
```